# In Ubuntu 9.10, how do I check my color depth?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, display, lcd, colors

`xdpyinfo | grep depth` gives me many answers, I'm not sure which one I want. Google says to look at my xorg.conf, but Ubuntu 9.10 has no xorg.conf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type in `xwininfo` at the terminal then click in a window on screen, the "depth" value is colour depth.
( via [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=183550) )